# Form committee of $2$ out of $5$ women and $3$ out of $6$ man with additional requirements.

Tags: combinatorics

What is the number of ways of forming a committee that consists of $2$ out of $5$ women Ms. A, B, C, D, E, and $3$ out of $6$ man, Mr. A, B, C, D, E, F.

There are two additional requirements:

1. Mr. A refuses to serve on committee if Mr. B is a member
2. Mr. B only serve wants to serve if Ms. C is the member of the committee

Comment: How many ways to choose two women from five? Three men from six? Permutations and combinations? This is straightforward from the formula, isn't it? Where can you possibly be confused in a direct application?

Comment: There are additional requirements, where some combinations are prohibited. In the original subject, that was not clear, that's why I edited the subject a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. all committees: ${6 \choose 3} * {5 \choose 2}$
2. remove the committees with both A and B: $4*{5 \choose 2}$
3. remove the committees with B and not C: ${5 \choose 2} *4$
4. inclusion/exclusion: add the committees with A, B, not C. (You subtracted twice and have to compensate): $4*{4 \choose 2}$

Answer (score 0):

As @ астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг mentioned, this question is an application of simple combinatorics.

The number of ways of choosing  women from 5 women is $5\choose2$ while number of ways of choosing 3 men from 6 men is  $6\choose3$. So, The total number of ways are $5\choose2$$\times$$6\choose3$.

Comment: This is correct for the number of committees, but does not address the additional requirements.